# Email delay through Gmail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, incoming-mail

Some people at my company are experiencing a severe delay when receiving emails sometimes. We recently had an email that was delayed for 41 hours according to the header.

My question is: how can I tell from the header where the delay occurred?

Here is the header info:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@xxx.com
Received: by [IPv6 address] with SMTP id xxxx;
        Thu, 21 Jun 2018 12:09:37 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ADUXVKLqsR+/5f7yZylgc2gqka7aUXfxkHDqRSakERiAIWb1Z2F8mVXArCn5m9btBNOX2V33XedQNO3bGGc=
X-Received: by 2002:a17:902:26:: with SMTP id xxxx;
        Thu, 21 Jun 2018 12:09:30 -0700 (PDT)
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: [IPv4 address] is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postmaster@unknown) smtp.mailfrom=unknown;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=Vbyb+AsW
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: [IPv4 address] is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postmaster@unknown) client-ip=xxxx;
Received: by [IPv6] with POP3 id xxxx;
        ***Thu, 21 Jun 2018 12:09:30 -0700 (PDT)***
X-Gmail-Fetch-Info: xxx@xxx.com 1 pop.secureserver.net 110 xxx@xxx.com
Received: (qmail xxxx invoked by uid xxxx); 20 Jun 2018 02:04:40 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO p3plibsmtp02-04.prod.phx3.secureserver.net) ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
          (envelope-sender <xxxx@xxxx.com>)
          by p3plsmtp16-04-26.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (qmail-1.03) with SMTP
          for <xxxx@xxxx.com>; 20 Jun 2018 02:04:40 -0000
Received: from mail-io0-f181.google.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]) by bizsmtp with ESMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxxx; Tue, 19 Jun 2018 19:04:40 -0700
Received: by mail-io0-f181.google.com with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxx
        for <xxx@xxx.com>; Tue, 19 Jun 2018 19:04:40 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=CNMwscN/OeorZ5H/ZMHM0N9eSy/5w54myskOI89X1UA=;
        b=Vbyb+AsWWkvt4ALxO1tfg4chHf1zODZAFx0u7+7OlSt+R+fw7R+2RwCa8G641MdW7L
         CpNJcpkV/defZFONRd7SpYGpEFrYXB/WSAilCp4Dz+ZGxmUdik4zMeWX6FJvZBSLkzW3
         RQ6XVb/7+8ABei0bycGvze9VIJmvfr7Fqe72w4mRB376WBQXDX/VRDDxeBOMI1yi11Ia
         pcneUMziNWEv6lGxQ71hsgys1rJBHugCT4n9Ab1I7xlYP+qQKLdrIdWVkPyUuNsWVXy1
         HTfmg7Pi5rjNXNP2Z/sOxRvL4OzkFKfJzY5qULL+uNjB+z9aNwoA51ml2CzYaoHbvx/1
         Pohw==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date
         :message-id:subject:to;
        bh=CNMwscN/OeorZ5H/ZMHM0N9eSy/5w54myskOI89X1UA=;
        b=WgeItjuJ/SczklmIAVuO4fP3HkOpq+7I9HL7AX4qqPZWYbcLKxZ7EqC0L+yro+Nf24
         A2kRN6Ss0/PKDNI+m8KRksUM7ouKJBuMS0j3vdC6W6XSDh2giyFZWgPGIJ+oasG9o4hT
         yjJ3effdm/+t8aEUUnhwcGZb84Dxno2SQuX3NIy/FZSr8g4Wj74W8pzS9JxFwZrSIts/
         tqTXoq9r16wQ1Uc3asWCE+OxgOSSqMU4OjqsTrCbAJxe3VmHNKLx0i3SvIKGsJ35mY5y
         aRhSnTh6bD/CQsv4rG4DRVmaZPlvQ3E/qRSGGNOx1V+5O4C7Y0V2y+HMH0a086y05EUR
         lJSQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: APt69E01AtCKgYRa9k8oqiRcdsQ1nd4pLBVAHp090pVOMgv5wChJrpDq iH2QCAS68O687d5AwQpHOjtEdNzKkOEYD2dLu2o=
X-Received: by [ipv6] with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Tue, 19 Jun 2018 19:04:39 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
References: <CAFXPT5sF7QNT7R3AOYax1X_f1uyQMqpvA0NLns9QZNPQK5CJDA@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <CAFXPT5sF7QNT7R3AOYax1X_f1uyQMqpvA0NLns9QZNPQK5CJDA@mail.gmail.com>
From: Michael Levin <xxx@xxx.com>
Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2018 19:04:28 -0700
Message-ID: <CAG41SRVcqVT7zR-mpwtA-Da8R62=Wk8Oe4-brwCQ+1sUu0if=Q@mail.gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000aa82e0056f093846"
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfNGeegDGE0vOp3CtFbGY/u0tzcaMlefHESF2LVd5WkInd/aPebpIhSXeQerWq/G+l1S6o5C6jfFXm+tbigRtqTC0bZiqzug2FB/Nb4FAqysQMR8fRA8Y /YEPdJ1p6WOWmuMnCxGtX6TYjBtupu+tmWfOQM4gj6maTJ7pkMabrl+DoV5vFj1NHzlJWpak/3y3Ug==
X-Nonspam: None

--000000000000aa82e0056f093846
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

I've tried to block all personal addresses, but I've left something off that is needed for more info on what could be causing this, I'll be glad to share.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay is between the Qmail SMTP and POP server.

```
Received: by [IPv6] with POP3 id xxxx;
        ***Thu, 21 Jun 2018 12:09:30 -0700 (PDT)***
X-Gmail-Fetch-Info: xxx@xxx.com 1 pop.secureserver.net 110 xxx@xxx.com
Received: (qmail xxxx invoked by uid xxxx); 20 Jun 2018 02:04:40 -0000
```

By the way you can analyze headers using following online tools.
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/MHA/Pages/mha.aspx
https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx

Comment: Here is an updated URL for the Microsoft service: https://mha.azurewebsites.net/, as listed on https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365

Answer (score 0):

To fix problem create DMARC record in DNS for domain example.com:

```
v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;pct=25;rua=mailto:dmarcreports@example.com
```